# Basics of SharpZipLib. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, compression, sharpziplib

I have the following method in my code:

```
private bool GenerateZipFile(List<FileInfo> filesToArchive, DateTime archiveDate)
{
    try
    {
        using (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(GetZipFileName(archiveDate))))
        {
            zipStream.SetLevel(9); // maximum compression.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            foreach (FileInfo fi in filesToArchive)
            {
                string fileName = ZipEntry.CleanName(fi.Name);
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
                entry.DateTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
                zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fi.FullName))
                {
                    StreamUtils.Copy(fs, zipStream, buffer);
                }

                zipStream.CloseEntry();
            }

            zipStream.Finish();
            zipStream.Close();
        }
        return true; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OutputMessage(ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code generates a ZIP file with all the correct entries, but each file is listed as being 4 TB (both unpacked and packed) and creates the following error when I try to open it:

```
Extracting to "C:\winnt\profiles\jbladt\LOCALS~1\Temp\"
Use Path: no   Overlay Files: yes
skipping: QPS_Inbound-20081113.txt: this file is not in the standard Zip 2.0 format
   Please see www.winzip.com/zip20.htm for more information
error:  no files were found - nothing to do
```

The code is practically taken from the samples, but I seem to be missing something. Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Do you get the same result for other values of SetLevel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used to use SharpZipLib until I switched to [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) You may want to check it out as an alternative.

Example:

```
try
   {
     using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("MyZipFile.zip")
     {
       zip.AddFile("c:\\photos\\personal\\7440-N49th.png");
       zip.AddFile("c:\\Desktop\\2005_Annual_Report.pdf");
       zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
       zip.Save();
     }
   }
   catch (System.Exception ex1)
   {
     System.Console.Error.WriteLine("exception: " + ex1);
   }
```

Comment: As of about '09, SharpZipLib has equivalent APIs: Add `zip.BeginUpdate()`, change `zip.AddFile()` to `zip.Add()` and `zip.Save()` to `zip.CommitUpdate()`.

Comment: DotNetZip doesn't support portable projects, though.

Answer (score 3):

See the post by [Tyler Holmes](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/12/windows-xp-unzip-errors-with.html)

The issue with Winzip 8.0 and others is with Zip64.  Set the original file size when adding the ZipEntry and the error goes away.

e.g.

```
string fileName = ZipEntry.CleanName(fi.Name);
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
entry.DateTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
entry.Size = fi.Length;
zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
```

Current release zip utilities don't have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem which I solved by specifying the `CompressionMethod` and `CompressedSize` properties on the `ZipEntry` object.  In my usage, however, the zip was being created to group several very small files in one download rather than actually compressing the files, so I got away with using no compression (level 0) and using the file's actual size for the `CompressedSize` property.  Not sure how that would work if compression is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone having the same problem in the future: My problem turned out to be that I was using a truly ancient version of WinZip (8.0, I think) to view the files. Using a modern viewer (12.0) solved the problem.